# Why do some cryptographic signature npm packages (like superdilithium) convert text to an array of integers before signing?

Tags: cryptography, vectorization, digital-signature, post-quantum-cryptography

I found this example usage code in an npm repo that I've been examining https://github.com/cyph/pqcrypto.js/tree/master/packages/superdilithium.

```
import {superDilithium} from 'superdilithium';

const keyPair /*: {privateKey: Uint8Array; publicKey: Uint8Array} */ =
    await superDilithium.keyPair()
;

const message /*: Uint8Array */ =
    new Uint8Array([104, 101, 108, 108, 111]) // "hello"
;

// Optional additional data argument, similar conceptually to what AEAD cyphers support.
// If specified, must be the same when signing and verifying. For more information and
// usage advice, see: https://download.libsodium.org/doc/secret-key_cryptography/aead.html
const additionalData /*: Uint8Array */ =
    new Uint8Array([119, 111, 114, 108, 100]) // "world"
;

/* Combined signatures */

const signed /*: Uint8Array */ =
    await superDilithium.sign(message, keyPair.privateKey, additionalData)
;

const verified /*: Uint8Array */ =
    await superDilithium.open(signed, keyPair.publicKey, additionalData) // same as message
;
```

It looks like `new Uint8Array([104, 101, 108, 108, 111]) // "hello"` is an array representation of the word "hello." How is this array derived? And is this a common practice in preparing letter-based strings for cryptographic signing? Why not just sign the raw string "hello?"

Comment: Cryptographic operations usually work on array of bytes. The name of the used type vary with the programming language and some use singned other unsigned byte values but the general approach is always the same. In JavaScript such an array is the Uint8array. Conversion between string representation and raw bytes arrays is specified by the used character encoding (e.g. UTF-8).